# Is there a way to compile different modules in angular depending on the logged in user?

Tags: angular, webpack, design-patterns

The project is a platform that shows different components, depending on the logged in user. Each type of board is a separate module and has its own sub-modules and components. I wonder if there is a way to compile and load only the modules and components that are being  used by the currently logged in user.
For example if I log in as Admin, I want to compile only the components used to render the board from the Admin's perspective. Is that possible? Do I have to configure webpack somehow to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of skipping compilation you could just use lazy loading. Basically the user only loads the components he needs.

The simplest way to do it is to have an /admin and a /user route each loading the parent module of the modules you want the user to see

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'admin',
    loadChildren: () => import('./admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule)
  }, 
  {
    path: 'user',
    loadChildren: () => import('./user.module').then(m => m.UserModule)
  }
];
```

For more details, I'd recommend reading up on it here: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules